# Clone method behavior at memory level - java

Tags: java, object, clone, instance

when i am creating new object of Particular class using new keyword it occupies some memory in heap 
For example i have class `Xyz` and i am creating object of `Xyz` using new keyword and it occupies some 
memory in heap

```
Xyz xyz = new Xyz();
```

now assume that `xyz` have memory location `12@FFD`

same object create using clone method

```
Xyz xyzClone =(Xyz) super.clone()
```

my question is if `xyzClone` occupies different memory in heap than `xyz` than why we need clone method
we can achieve same behavior using new keyword ??? and if `xyzClone` occupies no extra memory than it may 
be behave like Singleton

Please clear my confusion why we need clone method ???

Comment: `12@FFD` is not memory location

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802118/why-we-use-clone-method-in-java

Comment: @JigarJoshi : i clearly mention that assume that we have some memory location.my quesion is why clone

Answer (score 3):

[`clone()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) creates `new` instance which has same *state* as the one from which it is cloned

Answer (score 3):

Creating a [`Object#clone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29) means you can create an object that is similar to another object but is not the same object.

By this when you say you have `cloned` an object, it means that there is a different object in the `heap` that has the same state. But if you alter this new object, it does not alter the original object

> my question is if xyzClone occupies different memory in heap than xyz
>   than why we need clone method we can achieve same behavior using new
>   keyword ?

the `clone()` copies the values of an object to another. So we don't need to write explicit code to copy the value of an object to another.

The copy constructor is used to create a copy of an object that is passed by value to a function. This is not an issue in Java, because all objects in Java programs are passed by reference.

If we create another object by `new` keyword and assign the values of another object to this one, it will require a lot of processing on this object. So to save the extra processing task we use `clone()` method.

**See also :**

- [why we use clone() method in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5802118/why-we-use-clone-method-in-java)
- [Cloning vs. Instantiating a new class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707612/cloning-vs-instantiating-a-new-class)
- [Prototype Pattern in Java - the clone() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203493/prototype-pattern-in-java-the-clone-method)

Comment: If you alter the new Object which has another object then it will alter original. Default clone does shallow copy.

Comment: @san De cruz : ok got your point have one doubt in mind if clone is not memory efficient than why we use it in prototype design pattern

Comment: @NiravPrajapati I hope last thread in my answer clears the point

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can implement the same functionality like clone by creating any new method in class. But clone gives you more control. By clone you can create shallow copy(default) as well as deep copy(if you want).

It's just in-built functionality of Object class which gives you control on object cloning.

Comment: can we make over program memory efficient using clone method