# what the syntax for clone method if the subclass extends abstract class?

Tags: java, clone

For example, **class A** implements clone-able and its an abstract class, **class B** extends **class A**.

Suppose I need the clone method only in **class B**.
Do I still need to use

```
A result = (A)super.clone();
```

in the `clone` method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java clone() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30078647/java-clone-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can just implement `clone()` in `B` as:

```
public B clone() {
    try {
        return (B) super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

Note: the `clone()` method is not defined in the `Cloneable` interface. `Cloneable` is just a so-called 'marker' interface. So `A` doesn't need a `clone()` method at all.

(You could also declare the method as throwing CNSE and let the caller deal with it. Note also that `clone()` and `Cloneable` are somewhat out of favor these days. Consider simply providing a copy constructor instead that takes a `B` and copies the values of its fields.)

Comment: thank you, so if i have some variables like int, string in A class, it will copy it as a deep cloning method? like it will create a new B object?

Comment: @naor It will create a new B object and copy all the fields over, even fields declared in a superclass of B such as A, but as to a deep clone, if it contained, say, a list, the clone would get a copy of a reference to the list. So if you modify the list in the original (say, by adding an item), the change would appear in the clone as well.